# Implement else-if scala statement in a better way

Tags: scala, if-statement, datetime-parsing

I work on a function in **Scala**, that gets a start date, due date and a time zone information as parameters. The function has to return the quarter label, looking like the following:

> 2020 Q2

**There are different cases that can happen:**

- due date is null, calculate quarterly label from start date
- due date starts with year 9999, calculate quarterly label from start date
- start date is null, calculate quarterly label from due date
- when both start and due date is available, they should be the same, return that quarterly label
- time zone info can be null, or both dates can be null, do nothing in these cases

I started the implementation - *ignoring some requirements for now* -, and ended up having like million if statements, and they are not even working on a way I want it to.

It calculates the quarter and everything, when both start date and due date is available, together with the time zone info. It skips when time zone is not available (correctly), but it doesn't work when start or due date is missing.

The code:

```
import java.time.{LocalDateTime,ZoneId}
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit._
import java.time.temporal.IsoFields

object someObject extends Serializable {

  def isEmpty(x: String): Boolean = x == null || Option(x.trim).forall(_.isEmpty)

  def quarterlyFilter(startDate: String, dueDate: String, timeZone: String): String = {

      val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
      val calculatorTZ = ZoneId.of("GMT+4")

    try {
          if(isEmpty(dueDate) == true || dueDate.startsWith("9999")) {
              val start = LocalDateTime.parse(startDate, formatter)
              val incomingTZ = ZoneId.of(timeZone)
              val incomingStart = start.atZone(incomingTZ)

              val calculatedStartDate = incomingStart.withZoneSameInstant(calculatorTZ).toLocalDate

              val quarter = calculatedStartDate.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR)
              val year = calculatedStartDate.getYear
            println("only start")
              year + " " + quarter

          } else if(isEmpty(startDate) == true) {
            val due = LocalDateTime.parse(dueDate, formatter)

            val incomingTZ = ZoneId.of(timeZone)
            val incomingDue = due.atZone(incomingTZ)

            val calculatedDueDate = incomingDue.withZoneSameInstant(calculatorTZ).toLocalDate

            val quarter = calculatedDueDate.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR)
            val year = calculatedDueDate.getYear
            println("only due")

            year + " " + quarter
          } else {
            val start = LocalDateTime.parse(startDate, formatter)
            val due = LocalDateTime.parse(dueDate, formatter)

            val incomingTZ = ZoneId.of(timeZone)
            val incomingStart = start.atZone(incomingTZ)
            val incomingDue = due.atZone(incomingTZ)

            val calculatedStartDate = incomingStart.withZoneSameInstant(calculatorTZ).toLocalDate
            val calculatedDueDate = incomingDue.withZoneSameInstant(calculatorTZ).toLocalDate

            val startQuarter = calculatedStartDate.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR)
            val startYear = calculatedStartDate.getYear
            val dueQuarter = calculatedDueDate.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR)
            val dueYear = calculatedDueDate.getYear
            println("both")
            startYear + " " + startQuarter + " vs " + dueYear + " " + dueQuarter
          }
      } catch {
            case e: java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException => {
              println("no timeZone info")
              null
            }
          }
       }
  def checkQuarter: (String,String,String) => String = quarterlyFilter
  val getQuarterInfo = udf(checkQuarter)

}
```

When I run this with the following test data:

```
val startDate = "null"
val currentDate = "2018-09-30 21:59:59"
val timeZone = "Europe/Copenhagen"

someObject.quarterlyFilter(startDate, currentDate, timeZone)
```

I get this error, even though that parsing shouldn't even be reached..

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException

Can you help me making this function better, and simpler? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, let's see what we can do with this.

Let's guard against an empty `timeZone` to start with, as it's an easy short-circuit, and we'll be glad to know we have a valid one later.  Two options here; you can either use a conditional `return None` (Java-style), or you can wrap the whole rest of the method up in a flatMap (which is my preference).  We'll also check the `ZoneRulesException` bit here and treat an invalid time zone as "no time zone" (which it arguably is):

```
Option(timeZone).flatMap(tz => Try(ZoneId.of(tz)).toOption) flatMap { incomingTZ => 
   // rest of method
}
```

> due date is null, calculate quarterly label from start date
>
> due date starts with year 9999, calculate quarterly label from start date

9999? Yuck.  OK, we can handle both of these cases reasonably well:

```
def parseDate(s: String) = Try(LocalDateTime.parse(startDate, formatter)).toOption
val validDueDate = Option(dueDate).flatMap(parseDate).filter(_.getYear < 9999)
```

(Technically your specs talk about the date string starting with 9999, so we should `.filterNot(_ startsWith "9999")` before parsing.  But this way round feels much cleaner and can be adapted to other date-based filtering more easily.)

Handling the start date is similar, except without the year filtering it seems:

```
val validStartDate = Option(startDate).flatMap(parseDate)
```

Now we have options for both inputs.  I think a pattern match on the cases might be easiest here, to work out which date to base the label off:

```
val dateForCalc = (validStartDate, validDueDate) match {
    case (Some(sd), Some(dd)) if sd == dd => sd // arbitrary, could pick either
    case (Some(sd), Some(dd)) => throw IllegalArgumentException(s"Start Date $sd != Due Date $dd!")
    case (Some(sd), None)     => sd
    case (None,     Some(dd)) => dd
    case (None,     None)     => return None // or whatever "do nothing" means
}
```

Great, so now we have either the start or due date in `dateForCalc` and just need to work out the quarterly label from it.  At this point we can just use the meat of all your existing if-else blocks:

```
val incomingDate = dateForCalc.atZone(incomingTZ)

val calculatedDate = incomingDate .withZoneSameInstant(calculatorTZ).toLocalDate

val quarter = calculatedDate.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR)
val year = calculatedDate.getYear
Some(year + " " + quarter)
```

I think this is a reasonably nice approach.  We do validation, parsing and date comparison up-front; so that by the time all that's done, you have your *relevant and validated* inputs available and it's just a matter of doing the boring logic of working out the quarter and year.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood requirements correctly, I would do it this way:

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

def quarterForDate(date: LocalDateTime, zoneId: ZoneId) = {
  val zoned = date.atZone(zoneId)
  s"${zoned.getYear} Q${zoned.get(java.time.temporal.IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR)}"
}

def calculateQuarter(startDateString: Option[String], dueDateString: Option[String], timeZoneString: Option[String]): Option[String] = {
  val startDateOpt = startDateString.flatMap(s => Try(LocalDateTime.parse(s, formatter)).toOption)
  val dueDateOpt = dueDateString.flatMap(s => Try(LocalDateTime.parse(s, formatter)).toOption)
  val zoneIdOpt = timeZoneString.flatMap(s => Try(ZoneId.of(s)).toOption)

  (startDateOpt, dueDateOpt, zoneIdOpt) match {
    case (Some(startDate), Some(dueDate), Some(zoneId)) =>
      val q1 = quarterForDate(startDate, zoneId)
      val q2 = quarterForDate(dueDate, zoneId)
      if (q1 == q2) Some(q1) else None
    case (Some(startDate), None, Some(zoneId)) =>
      Some(quarterForDate(startDate, zoneId))
    case (None, Some(dueDate), Some(zoneId)) =>
      Some(quarterForDate(dueDate, zoneId))
    case _ =>
      None
  }
}

val startDate = Option("null").map(_.trim).filterNot(_.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
val currentDate = Option("2018-09-30 21:59:59").map(_.trim).filterNot(_.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
val timeZone = Option("Europe/Copenhagen").map(_.trim).filterNot(_.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))

calculateQuarter(startDate, currentDate, timeZone)
```

- emptyness of parameter should be something handled outside of function
- since invalid and missing are handled the same way, I would just stick to Option
- formatting logic can be extracted to avoid repetition
- different cases can be handled with pattern matching to make logic clearer

Even if I got the requirements wrong, this should be easier for you to adjust to what this code should do.